# Solve $ z = c $ , where $z$ is a complex number and $c$ is an integer using the trigonometric form of z

Tags: complex-numbers

Knowing that the trigonometric form of any complex number  $$ z = r*(cos(\theta)+isin(\theta)) $$ with $ \theta $ a real number.

How do we find $\theta$ for any integer $c$ ?

For example if we have $ z = 1 $ we can write $1$ as $\cos(2k\pi)+i\sin(2k\pi)$ with $k=\overline{0,n}$ with $n$ a natural number , thus makeing $\theta$ be $2k\pi$.

But what if we have numbers like $2$ , $5$ or $8$ , or other complex numbers like $3+4i$ ?

Comment: Your question is not clear! What is $a$ you are talking about?  Title doesn't makes any sense! What is your actual question?

Comment: I edited it , i ment how do you find $\theta$ , howIby haveing for exmaple $z=r(cos(\theta) +isin(\theta)) = cos(2k\pi) + isin(2k\pi) $ it makes $\theta$ be $2k\pi$ ... I was wondering if there is a way to find $\theta$ if we had $ z=8 $ for exmaple , using the same algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Being $c$ integer is utterly irrelevant. If
$$c = a + bi = r(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta),$$
then
$$\tan\theta = \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} = \frac ba,$$
$$\theta = \cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

- $2=2\bigl(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)\bigr)$, with $\theta\in2\pi\mathbb Z$;
- $5=5\bigl(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)\bigr)$, with $\theta\in2\pi\mathbb Z$;
- $8=8\bigl(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)\bigr)$, with $\theta\in2\pi\mathbb Z$;
- $3+4i=5\bigl(\cos\theta)+i\sin(\theta)\bigr)$, with $\theta\in\arccos\left(\frac35\right)+2\pi\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

$$a+bi=\sqrt {a^2+b^2}(\frac {a}{\sqrt {a^2+b^2}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt {a^2+b^2}}i )$$

$$=r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta )$$